# Where can I find the gsutil.tar.gz file for version 4.66 of gsutil?

Tags: gsutil

The situation on my end is really very complicated<sup>1</sup>.  The bottomline, however, is that I *desperately* need to download an version of the `gsutil.tar.gz` file that is *older* than the one currently available at https://storage.googleapis.com/pub/gsutil.tar.gz.

To be more specific, I need to download the version of this file curresponding to version 4.66 of `gsutil`.  (The `gsutil.tar.gz` file currently available at the URL above is the one for `gsutil` version 5.9.)

**Q:**  Does anyone know where I can find older versions of this file?

(I did try https://archive.org without success.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Trust me, you would *not* want to read a full description of it, and, to be honest, I do not yet understand it 100%.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the file in https://pypi.org/project/gsutil/4.66/#files

You can also find listed gsutil versions under [release history](https://pypi.org/project/gsutil/4.66/#history).

Comment: Thank you!!!  (I'm bummed that I don't have enough rep to set up a bounty to give you in gratitude.)